# Is it possibe to pass parameters between Azure Logic App executions?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App that executes every 24 hours and I need to pass parameters between executions, is that possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to maintain or pass state between two runs *within Logic Apps*.

But you can always use an external store with a common 'key'.

- Blob Storage
- Redis Cache
- Service Bus
- Azure SQL

All options.